# Bitrix микроразметка верхнего меню

Tags: html, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Подскажите куда копать?
Нужно добавить на сайт микроразметку на верхнее меню. Над слайдером. Я с Битрикс еще только знакомлюсь. Не пойму, как редактировать само меню и его пункты как html-код.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВАРИАНТ 1.
Переводите страницу в режим правки (в правом верхнем углу административной панели), наводите курсор мыши на меню, рядом с появившейся шестерёнкой будет стрелочка вниз: её нажимаете, наводите на menu(bitrix:menu) и выбираете "редактировать шаблон компонента"

ВАРИАНТ 2.
Находите файл по адресу /bitrix/templates/ваш_шаблон/components/bitrix/menu/top_menu/template.php и редактируете его

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас буду пробовать.